# When using scatterplot in ECharts and then fetching data dynamically, it will flicker, what should I do

Tags: javascript, echarts

We get one piece of data every 2 milliseconds, and when the scatter plot is drawn, the scatter plot flashes,

Initial configuration

```
let option = {
  animation: true,
  animationEasing: "quadraticInOut",
  grid: {
    containLabel: true, // 包含坐标轴标签在内
  },
  xAxis: {},
  yAxis: {},
  tooltip: {
    trigger: "item",
    formatter: function (c: { data: any }) {
      let data = c.data;
      return `X:${data[0]};Y:${data[1]}`;
    },
  },
  series: [
    {
      symbolSize: 1,
      data: [],
      type: "scatter",
      itemStyle: {
        opacity: 0.3,
      },
      blendMode: "source-over",
      large: true,
      largeThreshold: 500,
    },
  ],
};
```

Obtain data according to the socket, and update the data every 2 milliseconds

```
let optionsUpdate = {
  series: [
    {
      type: "scatter",
      data: [],
    },
  ],
};

optionsUpdate.series[0].data.push(...toRaw(newVal.datas));
myChart?.setOption(optionsUpdate);
```

Data format [150, 123], [150, 124], [151, 124]

Little change in data

When drawing, the scatter plot of data will flicker when the data is about thousands or 1W bars

I've tried using animations to overshoot or caching data 100 times to render a chart once

However, flickering still occurs when there is a large amount of data`